# How to delete an route53 A record without knowledge of the target IP in AWS lambda?

Tags: boto3

It seems that the [change_resource_record_sets](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets) method requires both the Name (e.g. myhost.mydomain.com) and the target values of the record (e.g. 123.123.123.123) to do an `'Action': 'DELETE'`, however the target IP is removed from terminated instances, so it seems a full lookup of the resource records requires a full [list_resource_record_sets](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.list_resource_record_sets) scan to get that information.

Is there a preferred method to get the ip of a terminated instance, or to delete a record without knowing the ip in boto3/aws sdk?

**detail**: I have a autoscaling group which maintains 3 instances, and a python lambda that is triggered on termination of an autoscaling instance. During the creation of the instance a route53 A record was created matching the vpc private ip address, like this;

```
instance_id: i-0bfced710f9c11867
```

creates route53 record:

```
{'Name': 'webXXX-dev-euwest1-0bfced710f9c11867-mydomain.com.',
 'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': '10.69.98.116'}],
 'TTL': 60,
 'Type': 'A'}
```

However when the instance is terminated, the private and public ipv4 fields of the instance are unset in the lambda event (and on the terminated instance in the console). Therefore in order to use the [change_resource_record_sets](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets) method, I need to provide the IP address from somewhere else;

```
def delete_route53(host,ip):
    route53.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId=hostedzoneid,
    ChangeBatch={
        'Changes': [
            {
                'Action': 'DELETE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'Name': host,
                    'Type': 'A',
                    'TTL': 60,
                    'ResourceRecords': [
                        {
                            'Value': ip
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    )
```

So currently I have to do a lookup of the record in order to delete it;

```
response = route53.list_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId=hostedzoneid,
    StartRecordType='A',
    StartRecordName=domain,
    MaxItems="10"
)
```

and a bunch of code to recreate the Name and ResourceRecords for the DELETE action. This seems a bit roundabout, and is slow in the lambda due to remote call (which costs money)

Is there a simpler way to delete that record?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same issue using tags. When a new instance launches, it's tagged with its own ip address. Then upon termination we just parse the tags and use that to delete the Route53 host record. Terminated instance records are available for ~30 minutes, so that's been working just fine for us.

---

One thing to keep in mind, if you're working with Elastic IPs, this will not work. There's no event for when an Elastic IP is attached to an instance, so you would need to delay the trigger or else end up with the non-elastic IP in your tags.

Comment: `Terminated instance records are available for ~30 minutes, so that's been working just fine for us.` hm... problem with this, ofc, is that you're relying on terminated information sticking around and not being garbage-collected. Feel like it'd be easier to get this information *before* terminating it and then putting it somewhere persistent (e.g. a DynamoDB table or something) where you only delete it *after* you're sure the relevant Route 53 records have been deleted.

Comment: Sure, but that's twice as much work: new DynamoDB table, that needs sufficient read/write capacity, your lambda function now needs to insert the relevant information etc. But generally I agree, it's probably better that way, and I would definitely go that route for anything that's critical to you/your business.